# Adding date picker to google spread sheet forms

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I have a google spread sheet and a form with me, also got some code to add the date picker to the spread sheet form.I s there any way I can modify the existing form of the spread sheet , so that date pickers can be added , since google is not supporting that feature.

Here is the link for the date picker code.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_datepicker

Please Help.....

Answer (score -1):

Write your own form with Google Apps Script including all the questions of the form and add your datepicker.

```
function doGet() {
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Add animal");

  var verPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var nameLabel = app.createLabel("Name:").setId('namelabel');
  var nameTextBox = app.createTextBox().setName('nametextbox').setId('nametextbox');
  var bdLabel = app.createLabel("Date:").setId('bdlabel');
  var bdDateBox = app.createDateBox().setId('bddatebox');

  var addButton = app.createButton('Add' ).setId('addbutton');

  var clickHandlerAdd = app.createServerClickHandler("respondToAdd");
  addButton.addClickHandler(clickHandlerAdd);
  clickHandlerAdd.addCallbackElement(verPanel);  

  verPanel.add(nameLabel);
  verPanel.add(nameTextBox);
  verPanel.add(bdLabel);
  verPanel.add(bdDateBox);
  verPanel.add(addButton);

  app.add(verPanel);
return app.close();
}


function respondToAdd(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();  
  var name = e.parameter.nametextbox;
  var bd  = e.parameter.bddatebox;

  var File = DocsList.find("YOURSPREADSHEET");    
  var Id =  aFile[0].getId();
  var Ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(aId);
  var Sheet = aSs.getSheetByName("THESHEET");
  var NumRows = Sheet.getLastRow();
  var newRow = NumRows + 1;

  aSheet.getRange([newRow],[1]).setValue(name);
  aSheet.getRange([newRow],[2]).setValue(bd); 

  return app;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

FYI  Dates were added to Google Spreadsheet Forms in May 2013.  See https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDrive/posts/dfpVxqn1ouW